# On converting a Short to a Byte what goes on?

Tags: java, byte, type-conversion, short

I'm new to Java, from PHP, so spending some time/effort understanding types. Then I came across this:

```
    Byte bb = new Byte("127");
        System.out.println(bb.byteValue());

    Short ss = new Short("32727");
        System.out.println(ss.shortValue());
        System.out.println(ss.byteValue());
```

Outputs 127, 32727 and -41 ?

Can someone explain to me how it arrived at -41 when the Short 32727 is represented as a byte?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binary representation of 32727 is `0111111111010111`. The byteValue() of that is just the smallest 8 bits, so `11010111`

`11010111` is negative since it begins with a 1.

Taking the [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) (complement each bit and then add one) gives `101001` which is 2^5 + 2^3 + 2^0 = 32+8+1 = 41

So we have -41.

Answer (score 1):

Java only knows **signed** types. When you truncate 32727 to 8 bits (i.e. modulo 256), you get 215, which is -41 when interpreted as a signed 8-bit number (215 + 41 = 256 = 2<sup>8</sup>).

The choice of making the `Byte` type signed has caused plenty of criticism, since it adds a lot of subtlety to basic serialization operations, for which people generally prefer the `int` type for this very reason.

Comment: And unsigned 16-bit `char` ;)

Comment: Thx, I'd worked out the modulo bit, but didn't get any further with 215 - how silly of me.